# How can I delete a field translation in node?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

I am using a complicated melange of paragraphs with asymmetric translation, and in a few my nodes there is a stubborn translation that somehow is stuck.

Its a node that used to be translated, but then i deleted the translation.
I edited the original language paragraph field. but when i try to translate the node, the created content of that paragraph field is the old content.

I can delete all the related paragraphs that are relating to that field in that node in that language, and when i try again to create a translation, my paragraph field is just empty instead of showing the duplication of the original language.

So, i understand that i need to somehow delete the field's translation or mark the field as untranslated so that next time a fresh translation is created

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Paragraph fields aren't translated, they always refer to the same paragraph, so it would be a translation of the paragraph you need to delete

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is not the translation of the paragraphs. I deleted those and as i said in the question, after deleting the related translations, when i go to translate my node, the paragraph field is empty, but as there is content in that field in the original language i expect it to duplicate that content. this works in general site-wide. I just need a way to mark the field as not translated so that when i come to translate the node the usual behaviour of creating a new translation is envoked.